# Organising JSON object structure for performance

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, lodash

I have a list of 30k+ complex JS objects. Each object in the list has a name property.

I want to be able to find an object by name as quickly as possible without resorting to using a database.

3 questions spring to mind regarding performance.

Is it faster to query a flat list - `[{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}, {name: 'c'}]` or to query data with a nested structure - `{ group1 : [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}], group2: [{name: 'c'}] }` ?

2nd closely related question, is it faster to query this:

```
`[{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}, {name: 'c'}]`
```

OR this:

```
{ a: {name: 'a'}, b: {name: 'b'}, c: {name: 'c'} }
```

Thirdly, is native JS code faster or should I use lodash (because my code is likely to be less performant???) Are there any libs to help with this - either JavaScript libs or npm packages.

Comment: It depends on what type of querying you are trying to do. This sort of micro-optimisation is usually pointless anyway. Focus on your actual performance problems. Lodash *is* native JS, it just native JS that someone else wrote. We've no way of knowing if the code they wrote is more efficient than code you might write.

Comment: This is a *primarily opinion-based* question because you're going to get a lot of **opinions** based of experiences, Etc.  Therefore, this question should be closed.

Comment: None of this is in any way related to JSON.

Comment: Secondly, there is no "querying" involved here. You simply access the data. If you know where it is, storing it differently won't impact performance. If you don't know where it is, storing it differently can impact performance based on what information you have and don't have about the data/location before searching for it. It all depends on your application's needs.

Comment: The best thing would probably be to use a streaming JSON parser instead of `JSON.parse`. The structure does not really have an impact here.

Comment: To fetch a single item by some unique identifier *(as `name` appears to be)*, this `{ a: {name: 'a'}, b: {name: 'b'}, c: {name: 'c'} }` is usually way faster than `[{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}, {name: 'c'}]`. `O(1)` vs `O(n)`. The array is more handy and probably faster when you need to get a subset of your data; think Array#filter. Usually I have both structures side by side. But that introduces new complexity, as you now need to take care to keep both structures in sync. Like when you add/remove/replace an item.

Comment: Hashtable access with known key: `O(1)`. Finding an item it an unsorted array: `O(n)` where `n` is the array length. Finding an item in a sorted array: `O(log(n))` where `n` is the length of the array. For a 30k length, you'll almost certainly want to hash on names if you need to call by name rather than repeatedly search the array, but if you're going to do the latter at least sort it first, do some caching, etc.

Comment: ... or to frame it in terms of your question, doing `b` for your data (as a hashtable) takes 1 unit of time. Doing binary search on the sorted data (as an array) takes 14 times as long. Doing a brute-force search on your data (as an array) takes 30000 times as long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Objects in JS are dictionaries, meaning `obj.x` is faster (probably instant) than "find x in list". But you won't benefit from this with that structure, you need to find `obj.*.name` where `name = "a"` so it'd be the same as searching in an array/list.

2) If in the second example (`x: {name: 'x'}`) x the key is always the same as 'x' the string (value of `name`) then "finding" x in the object is as simple as `obj['x']` (which is the same as `obj.x`) because it's a dictionary. It's already "indexed" by key.

3) `_.find` is in no way faster or slower than looping through the data yourself and `return`ing when you've found something.

Use a database. You could go with an in-memory JS "search" index. I used http://fusejs.io/ before but not on that amount of data.